# Show picture while hovering over DropDownList items ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

**EDIT**
 Apparently you can not do what I thought of, I found no solution for my problem.

I am currently learning ASP.NET, and I would like to associate a picture with every item from an asp:DropDownList. I am using C# as the programming language, and an ASP.NET WebForm.

Example of what I am trying to do:

When the user opens a DropDownList, and hovers through its items, in some sort of a picturebox I'd like to show every item's associated image.

Imagine a DropDownList containing: Dog ,Cat ,Lion.

When the user opens the DropDownList and hovers over these items, either a dog or a cat or a lion would be shown next to the DropDownList.

I do not wish to use the SelectedIndexChanged event of DropDownList, because that is triggered only after an option is selected.

Thank you!

One more thing, I know that I am supposed to use jQuery or/ and CSS, but please be specific if you have a solution.

Comment: You used the term "hover" and you tagged the question with `javascript`, so you must have some idea where to start. You will get more help if you make an attempt and show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

In code-behind add the items to the DropDownList and loop through them to add the custom attribute imageName:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Dog", "Dog", true));
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Cat", "Cat", true));
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Lion", "Lion", true));

string[] imageArray = new string[] { "dog.jpg", "cat.jpg", "lion.jpg" };
int i = 0;
foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)
{
    item.Attributes.Add("imageName", imageArray[i]);
    i++;
}
```

And then on the .aspx page bind the hover function to the DropDownList options to show the image:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %> option").hover(function (event) {
        var image = $(this).attr("imageName");
        document.getElementById('imagePanel').innerHTML = '<img src="' + image + '">';
    });
});
</script>

<div id="imagePanel"></div>
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

You may want to add [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to the script to delay the loading of images when hovering.

Comment: Apparently you can not add a hover event to a DropDownList element.